# XtraGrid has been modified

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I need to know if an `XtraGrid` has been modified (value changed or rows added).

I can make a `boolean var` and change it on `GridView_CellValueChanged`:

```
void suppGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e) {
    isModified = true;
}
```

or
I can read all DataSource and check the [DataRow.RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) property value (`Modified` or `Added`):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSource.Rows) {
    if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified || row.RowState == DataRowState.Added) 
        return true;
}
```

Do you know a simpler method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can know whether the data table changed in the following way:

```
DataTable changes = table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added | DataRowState.Modified);
bool isModified = (changes != null);
```

here `table` is a DataTable.
From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8.aspx):

> **DataTable.GetChanges Method:**
>   Gets a copy of the DataTable containing all changes made to it since it was last loaded, or since AcceptChanges was called, filtered by DataRowState.

**Remark:**
If no rows of the desired DataRowState are found, the method returns **null**.

Comment: @Zyku: I've updated the answer a bit to avoid possible NullReferenceException.

Comment: @DmitryG , yes i did this in my project, after getting error of null , thanks